# How merge two sequences into one?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, linq

I have some working code that retrieves data from data base. It is interesting for me to get some better code for my solution. Are there some ways to combine two queries into one or something like this?

```
Dim customerTitlesAndIDs = contex.CustomerTable.Select(Function(row) New
                           With {.ID = row.ID, .CustomerTitle = row.Title}).ToList()

Dim cutomerIdPayment = contex.CustomerPayments.Select(Function(table) New 
                       With
                       {
                           .ID = table.CustomerID,
                           .Range = table.PaymentsRange,
                           .Values = table.Values
                       }).ToList()

Dim customerInfos As New List(Of SCustomerInfo)

For Each customer In customerTitlesAndIDs

    Dim cID As Integer = customer.ID
    customerInfo.Add(New SCustomerInfo(CreateCustomerTable(), cID, customer.CustomerTitle))

    For Each cutomerPayments In cutomerIdPayment

        If cutomerPayments.ID = cID Then
            Dim rangeValue(1) As Object
            rangeValue(0) = cutomerPayments.Range
            rangeValue(1) = cutomerPayments.Values
            Dim dtRow As DataRow = customerInfos.Last().PaymentTable.NewRow()
            dtRow.ItemArray = rangeValue
            customerInfos.Last().PaymentTable.Rows.Add(dtRow)
        End If
    Next
Next

Return customerInfos
```

**Same code with C# (hope no syntax errors occurred):**

```
var customerTitlesAndIDs = contex.CustomerTable.Select(row => new
                           { .ID = row.ID, .CustomerTitle = row.Title }).ToList();

var cutomerIdPayment = contex.CustomerPayments.Select(table => new
                       {
                           .ID = table.CustomerID,
                           .Range = table.PaymentsRange,
                           .Values = table.Values
                       }).ToList();

List<SCustomerInfo> customerInfos = new List<SCustomerInfo>;

foreach (var customer in customerTitlesAndIDs)
{
    int cID = customer.ID;
    customerInfos.Add(new SCustomerInfo(CreateCustomerTable(), cID, customer.CustomerTitle));

    foreach (var cutomerPayments in cutomerIdPayment)
    {
        if (cutomerPayments.ID = cID)
        {
            object[] rangeValue = new object[1] {cutomerPayments.Range, cutomerPayments.Values};
            DataRow dtRow = customerInfos.Last().PaymentTable.NewRow();
            dtRow.ItemArray = rangeValue;

            customerInfos.Last().PaymentTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        }
    }
}
```

SCustomerInfo represented by folowing `Structure` (code is simplified):

```
Public Structure SWindAltitude
    Public PaymentTableAs DataTable
    Public Title As String
    Public ID As Integer
End Structure
```

Both C# and VB.NET solutions will be helpful.

Comment: maybe its just me but I feel like if you would accept a C# answer you should post C# code as well, because I'm not well-versed in VB

Comment: Do you think it will be nice to place into one question C# and VB.net code?

Comment: C# and VBNET can be threated as one, while both depends on .NET Framework and both languages can be easily translated between both, For me is right if one person asks for both a C#/VBNET solution in a .NET question of a specific language. but some ... ... people like to downvote those stupid things or remove tags.

Comment: Use JOIN `contex.CustomerTable.Join(contex.CustomerPayments, ...)`

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, utilizing navigation properties (you'll probably have to massage it as I don't know the exact makeup of your data structures):

```
var customerQuery = context.CustomerTable.Select( ct => 
    new { 
        ct.ID, 
        ct.CustomerTitle, 
        // use nav property to get customer payments
        CustomerPayments = ct.CustomerPayments.Select( cp => 
            new { 
                Range = cp.Range, 
                Values = cp.Values } ) } );

return customerQuery.ToArray()
    .Select( cq => 
        {
            var retVal = new SCustomerInfo( CreateCustomerTable(), cq.ID, cq.CustomerTitle ); 

            foreach( var customerPayment in cq.CustomerPayments )
            {
                var dtRow = cq.PaymentTable.NewRow();

                dtRow.ItemArray = new object[] { customerPayment.Range, customerPayment.Values };

                retVal.PaymentTable.Rows.Add( dtRow );
            }

            return retVal;
        } );
```

Comment: why your call `ToArray` before `Select`?

Comment: to enumerate the results from the DB - can't have a constructor with parameters in a LINQ to Entities select statement.  Calling `ToArray()` gets the results from the DB and we're now using `IEnumerable<T>.Select(...)`.  Without `.ToArray()`, we'd still be using the L2E `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: It's possible that the constuctor for `SCustomerInfo` and the function `CreateCustomerTable()` could be re-factored to work with L2E, depending on what they do, exactly.

Comment: I'm interested in learning how, @pseudocoder.  It's instantiating a client side object with a non-parameterless constructor.  I'm quite certain that's not possible within L2E - you would get a "only parameterless constructors allowed" exception message

Comment: @Moho I meant it's possible that work could be done using only parameterless constructors and object initializers, "depending on what they do, exactly".  Obviously there's no way for us to tell without seeing the source.

Comment: For instance it's possible that something like this would do the same thing: `customerQuery.Select(cq => new SCustomerInfo{ PaymentTable = cq.CustomerPayments.Select(cp => new {cp.Range, cp.Values}),ID = cq.ID, Title = cq.CustomerTitle});`

Comment: that is a parameterless constructor with object initializer.

Comment: @Moho You don't seem to understand, my comment was directed at the question poster, not you.  I am not suggesting that you can improve your answer, I'm trying to tell the question poster that with a little refactoring it's *possible* he can defer query execution longer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41974/discussion-between-pseudocoder-and-moho)

Comment: @Moho, I don't understand what you mean
        // use nav property to get customer payments
I tried do like  CustomerPayments = ct.CustomerPayments.Where((cp, i) i = ct.ID).Select( cp => 
            new { 
                Range = cp.Range, 
                Values = cp.Values } ) } );
But it fails. Two tables are connected by customer ID (in first - just ID, in second - CustomerID).

Comment: do you have a navigation property defined in your `CustomerTable` entity referencing a collection of `CustomerPayments`?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right in c# with linq it will be something like this

```
var customerInfos = customerTitlesAndIDs.Select((c)=>{
                        var ci = new SCustomerInfo(CreateCustomerTable(), c.ID, customer.CustomerTitle);
                        ci.PaymentTable = ci.PaymentTable.AsEnumerable().Union(
                                          cutomerIdPayment.Where(j=>j.ID == c.ID)
                                                          .Select(j=>{
                                                              var dtRow = ci.PaymentTable.NewRow();
                                                              dtRow.ItemArray = new object[] {
                                                                  customerPayment.Range,
                                                                  customerPayment.Values 
                                                              };
                                                              return dtRow;
                                          })).CopyToDataTable();
                        return ci;
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I doubt `new SCustomerInfo(x,x,x)` can be called from within a LINQ to Entities query as you have it here; see @Moho answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Linq provided function Sequence.concat() as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386979(v=vs.100).aspx